# UTF-8 encoded Java String into Properties

Tags: java, utf-8, properties, io

I have a single UTF-8 encoded String that is a chain of key + value pairs that is required to be loaded into a Properties object. I noticed I was getting garbled characters with my intial implementation and after a bit of googling I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863838/problem-with-java-properties-utf8-encoding-in-eclipse) which indicated what my problem was - basically that Properties is by default using ISO-8859-1. This implementation looked like

```
public Properties load(String propertiesString) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(propertiesString.getBytes()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
        }
        return properties;
    }
```

No encoding specified, hence my problem. To my question, I can't figure out how to chain / create a `Reader` / `InputStream` combination to pass to `Properties.load()` that uses the provided `propertiesString` and specifies the encoding. I think this is mostly due to my inexperience in I/O streams and the seemingly vast library of IO utilities in the java.io package.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: [Java properties UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75004202/20912350) it's a better solusion to this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [`Reader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) when working with strings. [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html)s are really meant for binary data.

```
public Properties load(String propertiesString) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesString));
    return properties;
}
```

Comment: That constructor doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, I did checkout [StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html), but I saw no such constructor.

Comment: Cheers Matt, just tried this solution successfully. Didn't use StringReader initially cause I had my blinders on looking for control over the encoding. Thanks very much for your assistance. Upvote + accept for you my friend.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Apologies for initially pointing you toward a nonexistent constructor.

Answer (score 3):

```
   private Properties getProperties() throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("your file");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStreamReader);
        return properties;
    }
```

then usage

```
System.out.println(getProperties().getProperty("key"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(propertiesString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
properties.load(bais);
```

Comment: I had to use this instead of the `StringReader` in order to support Android SDKs older than android-9.