# File appending in servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets, append

The following code appends data to the given file in java application. But when put this code in servlet, the file becomes empty. Why this?

```
try {            
  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\root.properties", true), "UTF-8");
  BufferedWriter fbw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
  String s = "root.label.1130.2=قسيمات";      
  fbw.write(new String(s.getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
  fbw.newLine();
  fbw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The string does contain non-ISO-8859-1 characters after the equals sign.
You may want to check that the Java compilation accepts UTF-8 input, i.e. `javac -encoding UTF-8`. Also, replace "iso-8859-1" with "UTF-8" in `getBytes()`.

See http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html#javaencoding_sourcefiles for a nice write-up and other ways to encode the  constant string.

Comment: @magaert:I get the correct output when I create a new file. But while appending there are problems in writing and in encoding.

Comment: Oh, that focuses the question a bit. Also, you are aware that Java properties are usually ISO-8859-1 (with character quoting)? Are you sure you can read the UTF-8 properties file? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040771/1037626

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are seeing any exception which might be thrown?  Perhaps your servlet doesn't have permission to write to the file.  I would try to debug your program to see what happens when this code is run.

---

What you are doing will corrupt many of the characters, but you should still get a file.

When I run this code I get a file with

```
root.label.1130.2=??????
```

which is what you would expect to get.

If I run this code

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("root.properties", true), "UTF-8"));
String s = "root.label.1130.2=قسيمات";
pw.println(s);
pw.close();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("root.properties"), "UTF-8"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        char ch = line.charAt(i);
        if (ch >= ' ' && ch < 127)
            System.out.print(ch);
        else
            System.out.printf("\\u%04x", (int) ch);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

prints the following, showing that the Arabic characters have not been mangled.

```
root.label.1130.2=\u0642\u0633\u064a\u0645\u0627\u062a
```

the file now contains

```
root.label.1130.2=قسيمات
```

as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that the question marks are not present in the Servlet source code file after you copied-and-pasted the snippet?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey:I get the correct output when I create a new file. But while appending there are problems in writing and in encoding.

Comment: @1355 I can't see how your encoding would ever work.  Have you tried the code I suggested? This does work when appending (as I have shown)

Comment: @Peter : Unfortunately that also does not work for me even in simple java aaplication. It writes as "root.label.1130.2=??????"

Comment: @1355 and you are reading as UTF-8 in a console which supports Arabic characters.  What do you see if you open the file in wordpad?

Comment: @1355 Try the example I have given now.

Comment: @peter : now also the same. file losts its content also. I am using netbeans for development.