# Supporting i18n in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Till now, our web application supports only English. Now we have to provide support for Italian as well. There is GWT module for some functionality. To support the Italian language I have added below line in the file "**APP_Module.gwt.xml**"

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="it"/>
```

I have also placed "XXX_it.properties" file under the source code where the properties file for en is kept.

Setting the locale in the jsp by following line:

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=${locale}">
```

Now, the issue is how to compile the code. I am debugging the application but it is not hitting the client code of GWT presented under WEB-INF/src.

I am very new to GWT. Please suggest how can I compile the code or there is no need of compilation. It will automatically take the changes done in "APP_Module.gwt.xml" and there is some other issue. How can I see logs of GWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add support for locales to GWT application, you need to do the following in your xxx.gwt.xml:

under `<module>` add this to include the support:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
```

and this to configure it:

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en,it"/>
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>
```

Add all your property files under some package like this:

```
src/main/resources/foo/bar/client/i18n/MyMessages.properties
src/main/resources/foo/bar/client/i18n/MyMessages_it.properties
```

Then you need to tell GWT to compile them into classes. This is example from a pom.xml file (if you don't use maven, you will have to use a different way, but you still need to configure it).

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1.google</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>i18n</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <i18nMessagesBundles>
                    <resourceBundle>foo.bar.client.i18n.MyMessages</resourceBundle>
                </i18nMessagesBundles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Then you need to recompile the code. In maven `mvn compile`. And that's all, you will have your messages in generated sources folder ready to use.

Comment: Most of the information can be found here: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n

Comment: Thanks @sm4 Its working fine. But now what happening is the characters like ù,ì are not displayed correctly. Is there any place where we set encoding?

Comment: This is most likely because you are putting UTF-8 (or any other encoding) into .properties directly. These files must be in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Try using the plugin from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/863838/1667977 Correct way is to have all special characters in properties escaped, this plugin will do it for you.

Comment: And of course your jsp page hosting the script can define encoding like this: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: I am loading the properties file in GWT using blow line GWT.create(propertiesFile.class); any idea in which encoding this reads the properties file?

Comment: This is a wrong question. You are creating the class using GWT deferred binding. This has nothing to do with encoding. Encoding of the property file that gets compiled into a class is ISO-8859-1 and you tried to put there UTF-8 (or else) character. Use the plugin and you will see the difference.

Comment: Tried ResouceBundle tool as well but no difference still wrong characters are displayed.Any other option?

Comment: Then maybe it's time to create a new question :) Last thing, try playing with the page encoding in your jsp using <meta> tag

Comment: Hope to see you answering on new question :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For seeing the logs of gwt you can use gradlew gwt also you can use it to compile the code too.