# configuration to encode Hibernate Validator customized error messages through Spring Framework

Tags: spring-3, hibernate-validator, spring-4, spring-validator

I am working with Spring (4.0.5) and Hibernate Validator (5.1.2.Final)

I already have working the error messages through a .properties file, **it works too about i18n**.

- It in a **standalone** and **testing** (JUnit) environment, by the moment. I don't want include the Web environment yet to keep the things simple.

I have the following:

For the **ValidationMessages_es_PE.properties** file (in spanish)

```
person.salary.digits=Dato invalido '${validatedValue}', máximo tamaño no decimal permitido es {integer}, máximo tamaño decimal permitido es {fraction}
```

About the infrastructure

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource(){
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("com.manuel.jordan.validation.messages.ValidationMessages");
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean(){

LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(resourceBundleMessageSource());

        MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator messageSourceResourceBundleLocator = new MessageSourceResourceBundleLocator(resourceBundleMessageSource()); 
        ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator resourceBundleMessageInterpolator = new ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator(messageSourceResourceBundleLocator);
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setMessageInterpolator(resourceBundleMessageInterpolator);

        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }


}
```

Observe I have `setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8")`

The test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=ValidatorConfiguration.class)
public class InvalidPersonValidation03Test {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InvalidPersonValidation03Test.class);

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    public InvalidPersonValidation03Test(){
        LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(new Locale("es","PE"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidNullId(){
    ...
```

Part of the output is the following

```
- >>>testInvalidFractionSalary
- ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Dato invalido '1578.100', m�ximo tama�o no decimal permitido es 4, m�ximo tama�o decimal permitido es 2', propertyPath=salary, rootBeanClass=class com.manuel.jordan.domain.PersonValidation03, messageTemplate='{person.salary.digits}'}
- ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Dato invalido '1578.100', m�ximo tama�o no decimal permitido es 4, m�ximo tama�o decimal permitido es 2', propertyPath=salary, rootBeanClass=class com.manuel.jordan.domain.PersonValidation03, messageTemplate='{person.salary.digits}'}
```

The characters `ñ` and `á` are not showing how it is expected

My IDE already has

`Preferences -> Workspace -> Text file encoding` with **UTF-8**

What extra missing configuration I need?

Comment: Try to set the `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to the server.

Comment: Thanks, where I should apply that? I tried on `JUnit->Run Configurations -> Arguments` in `VM arguments` or `Program arguments` and same bad results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the community

I have read this post
[Problem with Java properties utf8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863838/problem-with-java-properties-utf8-encoding-in-eclipse)

Therefore consider in use this easy and very useful tool
[ResourceBundle Editor](https://github.com/essiembre/eclipse-rbe)

It works for Eclipse and Spring Tool Suite

Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use unicode characters like this in a properties file. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PropertyResourceBundle.html

> In that case, characters that cannot be represented in ISO-8859-1
>   encoding must be represented by Unicode Escapes as defined in section
>   3.3 of The Java™ Language Specification...

á would be \u00E1 and ñ \u00F1

Comment: Something is weird, I have other project working with .properties in spanish and portuguese and all works fine, the problem is now, the unique difference is that now I am working with Hibernate Validator..

Comment: Perhaps you know a tool that let me do quickly that conversion? creating perhaps a new file with the transformed data? Of course keeping the old one. Thanks

Comment: nativetoascii, it is part of the JDK. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle