# Chinese characters in properties files are not properly decoded

Tags: java, spring, jsp, encoding

I have used localisation for my application in Chinese and English. It is a Spring MVC application and I am getting the values from a properties file. I have encoded the JSP pages in UTF-8 and mentioned UTF-8 encoding in web.xml also.

If I hardcode a Chinese character in the JSP page, it is displayed correctly, but the characters coming from the properties file are garbled and displayed like *ç§ç®åç§°*.

When I am doing wrong ?

Comment: the code that reads the properties file should specify the correct encoding of the file.

Comment: Nothing related with your JSP but more probably with your properties file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the Java properties files are/must/should been encoded in  ´ISO-8859-1´ (Latin-1) by default. Thats an Java requirement.

To overcome this you can go two ways:

- escape the not Latin-1 characters by UTF-8 sequences in the property file: `back=Zur\u00EF\u00BF\u00BDck` (german word ("Zurück") with some none Latin-1 charachters)
- or you encode the properties files in UTF-8 and manipulate the way how Spring load the properties files.

I would go the first way (it is more standard) - Then I would recommend to use a tool like  [ResourceBundle Editor](http://essiembre.github.io/eclipse-rbe/) (it does the encoding stuff)

@See also this question and its answers:

- [How to use UTF-8 in resource properties with ResourceBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)
- [Java properties UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863838/java-properties-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)