# java.util.Properties encoding

Tags: java

I get different results on two different systems and don't know why.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(input)); //input is byte[]
```

On both systems input contains `"var=\\u00C4\\u00DC\\u00D6\\u00E4\\u00FC\\u00F6"`.

On my test system prop contains `"var=ÄÜÖäüö"`. (This is what I want)

On another system prop contains `"var=\xC4\xDC\xD6\xE4\xFC\xF6"`. This is `input` in hex, but why does `Properties` do this? I unfortunately know nothing about the other systems configuration.

Has someone an idea about the reason?

Comment: You should try to display the ASCII codes. My guess is that you have the same values on both systems but fail at rendering it because of the platform's default encoding.

Comment: How are you displaying the values? Is it different on each system?

Answer (score 8):

Java `.properties` files are encoded with `ISO-8859-1` (`Latin-1`), NOT `UTF-8`. All non-Latin-1 characters must be entered by using Unicode escape characters, e.g. `\uHHHH`.

An alternative is to use the `XML` format for properties, which IS `UTF-8`.

[Source: Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

[Also see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863838/java-properties-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

[And this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659929/how-to-use-utf-8-in-resource-properties-with-resourcebundle)

Comment: Thank you Stewart for your answer. I know that my byte[] input must be ISO-8859-1. I use for example "\\u00C4" insteed of "Ä". But prob.toString() should give me the encoded value ("var=ÄÜÖäüö"). But on a foreign system it is "var=\xC4\xDC\xD6\xE4\xFC\xF6". I don't know why.

Comment: To complete the answer, we can note that this will be changed with Java 9. See http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/226

Comment: @unknown I think you're going to have to tell us something about what is different between the systems. C4 is certainly the correct code. http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/latin1.html

Comment: @Prim - Well, that's not going to cause headaches for a million developers across the planet, will it? Many, especially in the corporate world, are still on Java 7, or even 6.

Comment: @Prim: That's only for PropertyResourceBundle, not for properties files in general; and even PropertyResourceBundle will fall back to ISO-8859-1.