# Resource bundle display incorrectly utf-8 characters in Placeholder of form:input tag

Tags: java, spring, placeholder, multilingual, resourcebundle

In my project, I'm using Resorce bundle to display multi language, everything  is ok except it's couldn't display values in placeholder:

```
<label>
    <spring:message code="home.address"/>
</label>
<spring:message code="home.street" var="bdstreet"/>
<form:input id="txtstreet" class="form-control" path="address.street" placeholder="${bdstreet}" />
<form:errors path="address.street" cssClass="error" />
```

English display is ok, but VietNamese is incorrect.
My config:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>language/home</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**" />
        <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>

<beans:bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <beans:property name="cookieName" value="lang" />
    <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="vn_VN" />
</beans:bean>
<!-- End Resource Bundle -->
```

[image: Vietnamese incorrect]
[image: English is ok]

Comment: Can you provide sample from your message resource? It seems you store strings in encoded state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah, I found my problem.

I have just changed BunderResource plugin to format my properties file. And it's working now.

(I used unikey with "NCR Decimal" before, and it display incorrect in placeholder's position)

I recreated properties file with BunderResource plugin:
[image: add Plugin to edit properties files]

That plugin will reformat for me.
[image]
result is:
[image]
@Ken Bekov, thank for you help :)
I use it in this:
[Java properties UTF-8 encoding in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863838/java-properties-utf-8-encoding-in-eclipse)

Comment: you found it. don't mention it. )

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `defaultEncoding` property in `ResourceBundleMessageSource` declaration:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basenames">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>language/home</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Also, check that you file stored in `utf-8` encoding.

About placeholders. It seems, that you store strings in encoded state. This means that when you'll show it in html, browser will automatically decode strings. But when you'll show it in placeholders, browser will do nothing, and will show them as is. Solution, don't encode stings in your resource. Just type strings with common letters. Example:

```
simple.string=Qu&#7889;c Gia  // now you store in this format

simple.string=Quốc Gia  // you should store in this format
```

Comment: It's still not working :(.
Everywhere displayed is ok, only in placeholder have problem. I don't know why.

Comment: @Ducthien I've updated answer regarding placeholders

Comment: I tried it but when I display wrong format, it's auto change to English

Comment: I used encodings is: NCR Decimal to store strings. It has proplem in placeholder

Comment: oh, my mean is if I store with this format:
  " simple.string=Quốc Gia  // you should store in this format"
It will auto change to English language when display in website. I don't know why